# Selenium WebDriver file upload issue on ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

On GitLab while submitting an merge request, Im trying to attach a file from local driver,when I click "Attach a file" button and when I select the file from local it will show up on the text area input.

[image]

When I try to automate through selenium, after selecting the file from local drive, I'm unable to attach the file as the input text area doesn't directly have local driver path of where the file is stored.

i.e. : the input text area should contain something like "C\test.PNG" but it has "![test](/uploads/2536727737372/test.PNG"

Is there a way we can still automate this scenario?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Not sure how to write one for this scenario.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.text-attach-file")).click().  This one opens up the windows tab which prompts to select a file from local drive, at this point we are inactive on browser which doesn't allow for selenium automation

Answer (score 0):

You can element.sendkeys the file path directly to "Attach a file" button element, and the file should get uploaded.

```
WebElement attachAFile = driver.findElement(By.id("attachAFile"));

attachAFile.sendKeys("C\\test.PNG");
```

No need of clicking the "Attach a file" button to upload the file!

Comment: I tried this one.. but I see this on the text area section where the attachment gets appended :(/uploads/Test.PNG) but it should be something like :  (/uploads/<keys>/Test.PNG). I have attached that format as a screenshot on the question

Comment: I think somewhere git saves the files to its temp storage and fetches from there..